# Displaying Huge Information on JSP Page

Tags: mysql, arrays, file, jsp

I have a jsp page where data are displayed directly from mysql Database. Due to the huge lump of data, sometime the jsp page shows white blank page. Is there any solution so that the information from Database are stored in ArrayList or File temporarily and when requested jsp page displays these result instead of requesting mysql database. 
    I am using Apache Tomcat, MySQL database and jsp to display the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done the solution.

1. Copied all the SQL statistics in respective CSV files and then stored them in the directory.
2. These data are called from JSP page. The result is JSP page is super fast now showing the statistics information.
3. In Every 15 mins CSV file is updated with the new data.

Advantage:
Whenever JSP page is requested to display statistics, it doesn't send heavy request to Database but gets the info from CSV. This enhanced the performance.